# Divide array into blocks where each block is a longest ascending (increasing) sequence

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to take a vector and split into sections.  the code requires me to create a separate vector when the ascending order stops like this: `[3, 5, 9, 21, 27, 15, 10, 13]` will get divided into three blocks `[3 5 9 21 27]`, `[15]` and `[10, 13]`.

I'm not supposed to use a loop so it would be helpful if somebody is able to help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please consider accepting an answer (the one which answered your question best) to indicate the system, that your problem is solved (green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 2):

No loops, one line, I hope it's alright ;)

```
a = [3, 5, 9, 21, 27, 15, 10, 13];

output = accumarray( cumsum([0; diff(a(:))] < 0)+1, a, [], @(x) {x} )
```

some explanations:

```
%// find out where the vector decreases:
da = [0; diff(a(:))]
%// and create a mask
mask = da < 0
%// sum the mask up cumulatively and add +1
subs = cumsum(mask) + 1
%// use accumarray to gather everything
output = accumarray(subs,a,[],@(x) {x})
```

---

If there is subsequent the same number, like here:

```
a = [3, 5, 9, 21, 27, 27, 15, 10, 13];
```

the solution above counts the second `27` to the first group, if you want it to be a separate group, change the mask to:

```
mask = da <= 0
```

Comment: +1 from me too.  I am always in favour of an `accumarray` solution

Comment: ... mine seems to be little faster, though :-)

Comment: so when i run this i get  
    [4x1 double]
    [        15]
    [2x1 double]
why are all the other numbers substituted with the dimensions of the newer matrices?

Comment: you get a "cell array". That's the way how they are stored, because you have vectors of different length, you can't store them in a normal array. `output{1}` will give you `[3, 5, 9, 21, 27]` , `output{2}` will give you `[15]` and so on. Or double click on the variable in the workspace.

Comment: @BlakeSack In addition to what thewaywewalk said, you can type `output{:}` or  `celldisp(output)` to see the contents of the cell array. This is very basic Matlab

Answer (score 1):

It can be done very easily with [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
x = find(diff(a)<0);
result = mat2cell(a, 1, [x(1) diff(x) numel(a)-x(end)]);
```

If you want a one-liner:

```
result = mat2cell(a, 1, diff(find(diff([inf a -inf])<0)));
```

Comment: same thing happens when i run this too i get     
    [4x1 double]
    [        15]
    [2x1 double]

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` function calculates the difference between adjacent elements of an array. An element that is negative in a `diff` result points to the place where the ascending order is "broken".

So:

```
 v  = [3, 5, 9, 21, 27, 15, 10, 13];
 dv = diff(v);
 nb = sum(dv <= 0);  % number of blocks
 b  = cell(1, nb);   % container of blocks

 ix  = find(dv <= 0);  % start indices of blocks
 ix0 = 1;
 for k = 1:nb
         ix1 = ix(k);
         b{k} = a(ix0:ix1);
         ix0 = ix1 +1 ;
 end;
```

My opinion is that *is hard* avoid using loops, however, the code above is much more "gentle" regarding the computation load compared to the brute force method of finding blocks element by element.